# Ruby - loop not breaking

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a secret number game where:

1. A number between 1 - 10 is selected at random
2. Player has 3 tries to guess the secret number
3. If player guesses wrong in all tries, or guesses the right number, they will be prompted if they want to replay the game.

My issues are:

1. the "attempt" loop won't break when playerInput == secret_number. It will only break when all 3 tries are used.
2. Can't get to print the message "Sorry, but you have no more tries" when all 3 guesses are used up.
3. I think my math is off too... with the attempts

The code is below. Thanks in advance guys!

```
puts "Welcome to the Secret Number Game! Please tell me your name"
player_name = gets.strip

puts "Welcome #{player_name}!"

puts "Guess a number between 1 - 10. You only have 3 attempts!"

restart = true

def guess_check( playerInput, secret_number, attempts )
    if playerInput > secret_number
        puts "Too high! try again!"
    elsif playerInput < secret_number
        puts "Too low! try again!"
    elsif
        playerInput == secret_number
        puts "Congratulations, you guessed the secret number! [#{secret_number}]"
    elsif 
        attempts == 0 
        puts "Sorry, you're out of guesses, the secret number is [#{secret_number}]"
    else
        puts secret_number
    end
end


while restart

    guesses = []
    attempts = 3
    secret_number = 1 + rand(10)

    while attempts

        attempts = attempts - 1
        puts "Guess the secret number, you have #{attempts} tries left"
        playerInput = gets.to_i
        guesses.push( playerInput )
        guess_check( playerInput, secret_number, attempts )
        puts "You've guessed #{guesses}"
        break if playerInput == secret_number || break if attempts == 0

    end

    puts "Do you want to play again? (y/n)"
    answer = gets.strip
    restart = false if answer == "n"

end
```

Comment: you guys are awesome. thanks sooooo much for the exlpanation. can't believe the error was the extra "break if". and thanks for breaking it down. im going to from now on, order my conditionals from least likely to most likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't working like you intend it to:

```
break if playerInput == secret_number || break if attempts == 0
```

If you break it out, it reads like this:

```
if attempts == 0
  if playerInput == secret_number or break
    break
  end
end
```

It only gets to a `break` if `attempts == 0`, and only then either because the first conditional in the nested if statement failed OR it passed. This should make it work like you intend it to:

```
break if playerInput == secret_number || attempts == 0
```

It doesn't print your used up guesses message because the conditionals for either the right or wrong answer were executed first. To fix that, your conditional needs to be in the following order:

```
def guess_check( playerInput, secret_number, attempts )
  if playerInput == secret_number
    puts "Congratulations, you guessed the secret number! [#{secret_number}]"
  if attempts == 0 
    puts "Sorry, you're out of guesses, the secret number is [#{secret_number}]"
  elsif playerInput > secret_number
    puts "Too high! try again!"
  elsif playerInput < secret_number
    puts "Too low! try again!"
  #else   <= this can actually be removed, the if statement will never get this far
    #puts secret_number
  end
end
```

I'm sure there's a better way to phrase it, but you want your least likely/highest priority if statement assessed first. In this case, the user's guess is guaranteed to at least be greater or less than the secret number, so those get assessed first, and it never really gets down to the end. You want to assess correct guess (1/10), then out of guesses (3/10), then greater than (1/2)/less than(1/2). The `else` will never trigger because all possibilities are covered by the above.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple change here:

```
break if playerInput == secret_number || attempts == 0
```

Your `||` condition was valid syntax but causing the unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I refactor your code.

```
puts "Welcome to the Secret Number Game! Please tell me your name"
player_name = gets.strip
puts "Welcome #{player_name}!"
restart = true

def guess_check( playerInput, secret_number)
    if playerInput > secret_number
        puts "Too high! try again!"
    elsif playerInput < secret_number
        puts "Too low! try again!"
    end
end


while restart
    guesses = []
    attempts = 3
    secret_number = 1 + rand(10)

    puts "Guess a number between 1 - 10. You only have 3 attempts!"
    while attempts

        playerInput = gets.to_i
        guesses.push( playerInput )
        # once guessed, should exit current loop.
        if playerInput == secret_number
           puts "Congratulations, you guessed the secret number! [#{secret_number}]"
           break;
        end
        puts "You've guessed #{guesses}"
        #if not guessed, then should check the number is low or high.
        guess_check(playerInput, secret_number)
        attempts = attempts - 1
        #if out of guesses, exit from current loop
        if attempts == 0
           puts "Sorry, you're out of guesses, the secret number is [#{secret_number}]"
           break;
        else
           puts "Guess the secret number, you have #{attempts} tries left"
        end
    end

    puts "Do you want to play again? (y/n)"
    answer = gets.strip
    restart = false if answer == "n"

end
```