# Instantiating classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

so this is a follow up to my question regarding my secret number game.

[Ruby - loop not breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396303/ruby-loop-not-breaking/30405185#30405185)

now I'm trying to break this into multiple classes/files:

main
player
secret_number
game

Instead of doing everything in one file, now I'm trying to break up the game into segments.

Below are the codes in each class. I can't for the life of me figure out how to connect the classes together (and it's kind of driving me insane...)

thanks so so much in advance guys.

main.rb

```
class Main
# Ask player for their name, and instantiate the game class

    $:.unshift (File.dirname(__FILE__))
    require 'lib/game'

# put code here print a welcome message for your user
    puts "Welcome to the Secret Number Game!"
# put code here ask the user for their name, and save it
    puts "What is your name?"
    name = gets.strip

    newPlayer = Player.new
    puts newPlayer.name
# put code here to create a new game, and start it
end
```

player.rb

```
require "main.rb"
    class Player
# this class will likely be simple, and just remember its name
    attr_accessor :name    
    def initialize( name )
    @name = name
    end
end
```

secret_number.rb

```
class SecretNumber
# this class will generate our secret number for us
# This class should initiate an array of numbers that range between 1 - 10.
# Use a method from the array class to select a random element from that array. This random number will be the secret number.
# This way the secret number is also a secret to you.

    attr_accessor :secret_number

    def initialize( secret_number )
        @secret_number = 1 + rand(10)
    end 
end
```

game.rb

```
#   This class holds most of the game logic and should:
#   Welcome players and inform them of the game rules.
#   Initialize the Player class.
#   Initialize the Secret Number class.
#   Prompt the user to choose a number, verify if the user guessed correctly.
#   If the user guesses incorrectly let them know if they were too high or too low.
#   Monitor how many guesses the player has before the game is over.
#   this class will be complex
#   we need to write logic to initialize a new game, and run the game loop
#   we'll want to write a few separate methods for unique tasks so that our
#   code is structured properly


require "lib/player"
require "lib/secret_number"

class Game

    attr_accessor :name, :secret_number

    def intialize ( name )
        @name = Player.new
        @secret_number = SecretNumber.new
    end

    restart = true

    def guess_check( playerInput, secret_number, attempts )
        if playerInput == @secret_number
            puts "Congratulations, you guessed the secret number! [#{@secret_number}]"
        elsif 
            attempts == 0 
            puts "Sorry, you're out of guesses, the secret number is [#{@secret_number}]"
        elsif playerInput > @secret_number
            puts "Too high! try again!"
        elsif playerInput < @secret_number
            puts "Too low! try again!"
        else
            puts @secret_number
        end
    end

    while restart

        guesses = []
        attempts = 3

        while attempts

            attempts = attempts - 1
            puts "Guess the secret number, you have #{attempts} tries left"
            playerInput = gets.to_i
            guesses.push( playerInput )
            guess_check( playerInput, secret_number, attempts )
            puts "You've guessed #{guesses}"
            break if playerInput == @secret_number || attempts == 0

        end

        puts "Do you want to play again? (y/n)"
        answer = gets.strip
        restart = false if answer == "n"

    end

end
```

Comment: You might simply have the require around the wrong way. The game starts in `main.rb` right? You would need to `require player.rb` in that file, as you create a Player object.

Comment: (1) Convention in Ruby is to use `snake_case` over `camelCase`. (2) Your question seems too long for a Q&A format. Not only do you include many comments, you just include a lot of code! We would be more than willing to help with a focused question on a single issue.